# If $f$ is holomorphic and $f(a) \neq 0$, then $\exists B(a,r)$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ $\forall z \in B$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $G$ be a region and $f$ holomorphic in $G$. If there exists an $a$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$, then because $f$ is holomorphic, it is continuous, so there exists a $B(a,r) \subseteq G$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ $\forall z \in B(a,r)$.

I saw this line in a proof and I was wondering why this is true.

Comment: If there was no such $B(a,r)$, then we could find a sequence $z_n\to a$ with $f(z_n)=0$ for each $n$. By continuity, $f(a)=0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think by contradiction. If $f$ is holomorphic (analytic) and $f \equiv 0$ in some open set, then $f\equiv 0$ always. Note that $B(a,r)$ is one such open set.